# Помогите с изображением! AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
import fileinput

sa = None


def _open():
    global sa
    sa = askopenfilename()
    print(sa)
    f = open(sa, "r", encoding='utf-8')
    content = f.read()
    txt.delete(1.0, END)
    txt.insert(END, content)


def _save():
    global sa
    global content
    content = txt.get(1.0, END)
    f = open(sa, "w", encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(content)
    f.close()


def _about():
    win = Toplevel(root)
    win.iconbitmap('First_String.ico')
    win.geometry('300x200')
    lab = Label(win, text="First string version 1.4\n"
                          "Developer:NewModernSoft\n"
                          "2019.02.16\n"
                          "Copyrighted by NewModernSoft©")
    lab.pack()
    img = Image.open("mnm.png")
    img.show()


def _exit():
    global sa
    if askyesno("Exit", "Saved changes?"):
        if sa is None:
            sa = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=(("text file", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
        _save()
    root.destroy()


def _newwindow():
    root = Tk()
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
    scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

    root.geometry("1000x800")

    root.iconbitmap('First_String.ico')

    root.title("First String")

    m = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=m)

    fm = Menu(m)
    m.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fm)
    fm.add_command(label="New", command=_newwindow)
    fm.add_command(label="Open", command=_open)
    fm.add_command(label="Save", command=_save)

    hm = Menu(m)
    m.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=hm)
    hm.add_command(label="About Program", command=_about)
    hm.add_command(label="Exit", command=_exit)

    txt = Text(root, width=110, height=500, font='14', yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    txt.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
    scrollbar.config(command=txt.yview)
    scrollbar.bind('<MouseWheel>')


root = Tk()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

root.geometry("1000x800")

root.iconbitmap('First_String.ico')

root.title("First String")

m = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=m)

fm = Menu(m)
m.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fm)
fm.add_command(label="New", command=_newwindow)
fm.add_command(label="Open", command=_open)
fm.add_command(label="Save", command=_save)

hm = Menu(m)
m.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=hm)
hm.add_command(label="About Program", command=_about)
hm.add_command(label="Exit", command=_exit)

txt = Text(root, width=110, height=500, font='14', yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
txt.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
scrollbar.config(command=txt.yview)
scrollbar.bind('<MouseWheel>')

root.mainloop()
```

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\vikto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter_init_.py",
>
> line 1705, in call return self.func(*args)
>   File "D:/FirstString/First_String.py", line 38, 
>   in _about img = Image.open("mnm.png") AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'

Comment: Полностью стёк ошибки покажите

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vikto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/FirstString/First_String.py", line 38, in _about
    img = Image.open("mnm.png")
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'

Answer (score 1):

*Делайте импорт только необходимых вам модулей классов и т.д.*

*У вас здесь*

```
from tkinter.filedialog import *
```

*Происходит импорт Image*

*Ну и здесь вы импортируете Image*

```
from PIL import Image
```

*И что по вашему должен делать интепретатор?)*

Comment: спасибо!За ответ

Comment: Но у меня картинка открывается в другом приложении,а не в самой программе,еще и в bmp

Comment: Какой bmp, Image.open("mnm.png")? Какое другое приложение? У вас в скрипте я не вижу что бы вы открывали через Pyhon другое приложение.

Comment: Я вам конкретно сказал почему у вас эта ошибка: AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду это img = Image.open("mnm.png")  img.show()  под другим приложением так я вам в ответе указал на вашу ошибку

Comment: У меня открывается в программе "Фотографии" и файл под совершенно под другим названием в формате bmp

Comment: Что должен делать ваш скрипт?

Comment: Текстовый редактор,а где изображение в функции,там создаётся дочернее окно и пытался сделать там,чтобы была логотип